# Android - upload photo and string using Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

I'm trying to upload photo and token to server using Retrofit 2, but my callbacks inside "call" method not called.

Tried several variations, none of them worked for me.
This is my last config:

Link: https://some_domain.com/cabinet/profile/upload-docs/address

Interface:

```
public interface UploadApis {

@Multipart
@POST("address")
Call<ResponseBody> uploadAddress(
        @Part("description") RequestBody description,
        @Part MultipartBody.Part photo
        );
}
```

Retrofit instance class:

```
public class UploadImageClient {

private static final String BASE_URL = "https://some_domain.com/cabinet/profile/upload-docs/";
private static Retrofit retrofit;

public static Retrofit getRetrofitClient(Context context) {
    if (retrofit == null) {
        OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .build();
        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okHttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();
    }
    return retrofit;
}
}
```

Upload function:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == this.RESULT_CANCELED) {
        return;
    }

    if (data != null) {
        UploadApis uploadApis = UploadImageClient.getRetrofitClient(MainActivity.this).create(UploadApis.class);

        Uri contentURI = data.getData();

        File originalFile = new File(contentURI.getPath());

        RequestBody descriptionPart = RequestBody.create(MultipartBody.FORM, InAppProperties.getInstance().tokenIsDemoPair.token);

        RequestBody filePart = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse(getContentResolver().getType(contentURI)), originalFile);

        MultipartBody.Part file = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("photo", originalFile.getName(), filePart);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = uploadApis.uploadAddress(descriptionPart, file);

        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call,
                                   Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                Log.d("Upload", "success");
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d("Upload error:", t.getMessage());
            }
        });
    }
}
```

EDIT: 
after 6 mins of waiting i got exception:

```
okhttp3.internal.http2.ConnectionShutdownException
```

Comment: May be your file is too big.

Comment: 200-300 Kbytes. Watching network profiler - always uploading something after picking image.

Answer (score 0):

Try extending timeout limit using `OkHttpClient`.

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .build();
```

If still not able to get exact error message then enable logging of retrofit, this will print all logs of networks.

```
  HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
```

So the final `client` looks like,

```
  OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .addInterceptor(logging)
                .build();
```

Comment: Increasing timeout like above is not a good approach. If you have big to upload you can use Service.

Comment: Still same error after around 6 mins. Seems like a problem on server side or im sending it wrong somehow.